# RichFaces 4.3.3 AM/PM selector is blank

Tags: jakarta-ee, richfaces, centos6, jboss6.x

I need 2 things from the calendar component.

1) AM/PM selector.  Right now, I can select the hour / and minute but the AM/PM is blank. Any idea why that is?
2) 12 hour clock instead of 24 hour.  With AM/PM working this would satisfy the requirement. But incase it doesn't, is there anyway to specify a 12 hour clock?

Code:

```
<rich:calendar value="#{bean.aTimeField}" id="aTimeField"  
popup="true"  datePattern="d/M/yy HH:mm a"
enableManualInput="true" required="true"
showApplyButton="true" cellWidth="24px" cellHeight="24px" style="width:200px">
<f:ajax event="change" execute="@this"  bypassUpdates="#{true}"  render="aTimeField"/>       
</rich:calendar>
```

Comment: The showcase uses lowercase `hh` for the minutes. Have you tried this?

Comment: Moreover, the [API docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_3_X/vdldoc/rich/calendar.html) don't agree with the code: `datePattern` is supposed to be a ISO-8601 spec string, but there's nothing in that standard that allows "HH" (it's `hh` and they're always 24h zero-padded). So my *guess* is that we're talking about Java's [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) here. Unable to confirm ATM, so leaving it as a comment. Bottom line: try "d/M/yy hh:mm a" as `datePattern`.

Comment: "d/M/yy hh:mm a" as datePattern worked perfectly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short story:**

You're actually forcing RichFaces to use a 24h format by giving `HH:mm` as part of the `datePattern`. Change it to `hh:mm a` to have AM/PM work as intended and [used in the showcase](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=calendar&skin=blueSky).

**Long story:**

The  [API docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_3_X/vdldoc/rich/calendar.html) say:

> datePattern [...] Used to format the date and time strings, according to ISO 8601 (for example, d/M/yy HH:mm a)

Where even the example indicates confusion since the standard [uses 24h format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times) and thus doesn't *have* a AM/PM distinction.

This works nevertheless because the [input component](https://github.com/richfaces4/components/blob/master/input/ui/src/main/java/org/richfaces/component/AbstractCalendar.java) uses the standard `javax.faces.convert.DateTimeConverter` to process `datePattern`. And this class' [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/convert/DateTimeConverter.html) states:

> If a pattern has been specified, its syntax must conform the rules specified by java.text.SimpleDateFormat.

And this format specs [distinguish](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) between

```
H   Hour in day (0-23)
h   Hour in am/pm (1-12)
```